# Sum of square product of I.I.D. Normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

All $a_i$,$b_i$ and $c_i$ $(1<i<10)$ are independent standard normal distributed variable by each other ($a_i$,$b_i$,$c_i$$∼$$N(0,1)$).

and I would like to know about expected value of combination of these variables, which is
$$E\biggr[\sum_{i=0}^{10} (\frac{a^2c^2}{a^2+b^2})\biggr]$$

I think denominator follows Chi-square distribution

but this equation seems that denominator and numerator are not independent so I have trouble solving this.

what is expected value of above equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without any heavy computation. First note that $c_i^{2}$ is independent of $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s. Next note that $E\sum \frac {a_i^{2}} {a_i^{2}+b_i^{2}} =E\sum \frac {b_i^{2}} {a_i^{2}+b_i^{2}} $ (in view of the assumptions on $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s) and this two add up to $10$). Hence the answer is $5$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer of my question. Your answer gave me clue.
But I still have one question about your answer. 

I can follow that expectations of left term and right term are same but how can i derive that the answer is 5?

Comment: What is their sum? $\frac {a_i^{2}} {a_i^{2}+b_i^{2}}+ \frac {b_i^{2}} {a_i^{2}+b_i^{2}}=1$ so the expectation is also $1$, for each $i$. When you add $10$ of these you get $10$.

Comment: I understood your answer thank you so much. 

E[$\frac{a_i^2 }{a_i^2+b_i^2}$ ] will be 0.5, and  E[$c_i^2$] is 10, so the product will be 5.

When I validate the value using MATLAB, this answer seems pretty accurate. Thank you for your kindness. Can I derive variance simillarly?